# How to obtain the exact dpi value of android device?

Tags: android, dpi

we can use `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi` to obtain a approximate dpi value of the device,but i eager to know how to obtain the exact dpi value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use DisplayMatrics.xdpi and DisplayMatrics.ydpi

```
xdpi    The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X dimension.
ydpi    The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension.

getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can accesss this through the class [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) and the field `densityDpi`.

Comment: Use DisplayMetrics.densityDpi can only obtain a approximate value.For example,a device with 149 dpi screen will return a approximate value 160 dpi.