# How to get same size of game elements on diff android screen sizes and resolution

Tags: android, graphics, pixel, screen-size

I’m trying to have a similar size of my game object on different android devices, that means different screen sizes and resolutions, is there any way to for example recalcualt for example 1cm to pixels.

I mean that recalculate it toward screen resolution and size and get number of pixels that would correspond to real life size.

I read about the device independent pixels, when you create android UI in xml, however it seems not good for me, as I’m doing it in OpenGL and simple would like to recalculate any real life size to pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the screen dpi might work.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7594607/931277) explains how to get it using DisplayMetrics.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the getHeight() and getWidth() methods to get your game View's height and width.
2. Define all your game object dimensions relative to your View's height and width.

Also, do not call getHeight() and getWidth() from inside your View's constructor, this will return 0 since your View surface is not created yet. I am using SurfaceView for my game and I am calling these methods in surfaceCreated() method.

Comment: no, this is wrong, I will have different sizes on different screen diameters

Comment: "recalculate it toward screen resolution and size and get number of pixels that would correspond to real life size"...if you are trying to get your object sizes relative to screen size this will get you exactly that...